# How to create and share a git branch with other developers?

Tags: git, git-branch

How can I create a new branch and push it to the remote and then share it with the other developers? I'm following the below steps. What's wrong, missing?

Developer A creates the following:

```
git branch myBranch
git push origin myBranch
```

Then the remote should be updated:

```
git remote update
```

Developer B and C create the same branch on their locals:

```
git checkout --track origin/myBranch
```

Then what? If the above steps are correct, then how should I configure the new branch? What should be the correct order of steps to follow for this problem?

Comment: That all looks correct to me, what issues are you seeing?

Comment: *“for this problem”* – You never explained your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create and checkout your new branch locally:

```
git checkout -b myBranch
```

Then push your new branch to the remote:

```
git push -u origin myBranch
```

Now your friends can check it out:

```
git checkout myBranch
```

Have a look at the documentation for [`checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) and [`push`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) for more details and options.

Comment: But when my friends use "git checkout myBranch" they get the follwing error: branch myBranch does not exist.

Comment: Do `git branch -r` to see if the branch actually exists on the remote; maybe the branch didn't get pushed successfully. Also, do `git remote show origin` on both your machines, to make sure that you're both pushing and pulling from the same remote.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are skipping the fetch from Developers B and C. If your shared project's repository is $ORIGIN and the branch you want to share is $MYNEWBRANCH

**Developer A**

```
 git checkout -b $MYNEWBRANCH # then make changes
 git add $FILES
 git commit
 git push $ORIGIN $MYNEWBRANCH
```

**Developer B/C** (if they have already cloned the repo earlier before your new branch was created):

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -t $MYBRANCH
```

Whenever Dev B and C want the latest changes, they can git pull, which is really just git fetch and git merge combined.

Comment: By shared project, do you mean the shared branch? It's master. Then should I use the following?

   git checkout -b mybranch
   git push master mybranch

Comment: I assume mateor meant `$ORIGIN` is the project's *repository*

Comment: Yes. git push $project $branch. The cloned project's name is origin by default/convention. So to push a new branch use ```git push origin newbranch```. Then co-workers fetch all refs and checkout as shown above.